# Selecting data with a range condition on two columns

Tags: mysql

i have some articles in my database

```
+------+--------------+----------+--------+
| id   | article_name | age_from | age_to |
+------+--------------+----------+--------+
| 1337 | article 1    | 30       | 60     |
+------+--------------+----------+--------+
| 1338 | article 2    | 16       | 35     |
+------+--------------+----------+--------+
| 1338 | article 3    | 26       | 28     |
+------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

The user can set some filters in the front-end. He can search articles that are made for people from 19 years to 22 years. There are also two input fields (Age from and age to).   The database should return this:

```
+------+--------------+----------+--------+
| id   | article_name | age_from | age_to |
+------+--------------+----------+--------+
| 1338 | article 2    | 16       | 35     |
+------+--------------+----------+--------+
```

How do i do that? i can't do it with `WHERE age_from >= 19 AND age_to <= 22`.

greetings

Comment: why will it return `article 2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flip the logic:

```
WHERE age_from <= 22
AND   age_to   >= 19
```

My favourite explanation of this kind of problem, courtesy of [Rudy Limeback](http://r937.com/) (aka r937): http://www.dbforums.com/6318776-post14.html

Comment: Thats the way to find **range intersections**. +1